# Include new sources and exclude existing

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I want to copy java sources from projekt let's say from packet com.my.app (in src/main/java...) to the same target but in

```
{project}/target/generated-sources.
```

When copying I modify on fly the source code by my maven plugin.

And my question:

How can I set in mvn pom.xml that maven takes the sources in target/generated-sources and do not take the same classes in

```
src/main/java/com/my/app.....
```

The generated classes in have the same package and the same name as classes in normal source: src/main/java

Is it possible?

I need it 'cos I want to replace for build source code.

I must insert some source code in place of my own annotation (modify java source code) and modified file copy to

```
/target/generated-sources.
```

Than during build I want to use generated source.

Problem is that generated classes of course have the same package and class names like the classes in `src/main/java/com/my/app...` and I have conflict in compilation.

Please help how to do it!

Comment: Either you generate the classes or not but not both. You have to make the decision to use the generated or the classes under src/main/java ..What kind of plugin do you use?

Comment: fyi - Crossposted at http://www.coderanch.com/t/619957/tools/Include-sources-exclude-existing